# Adding zero numbers to my decimal value

Tags: c#, binding, format, decimal, zero

I don't know why but I've been struggling for something very simple this day.

I'm working with decimal values assigned to the Text property of a Label which is inside a repeater at the same time.

In my repeater ItemDataBound I'm doing this:

```
//myValue eventually could be just an integer but I want it in decimal format.
lblTotal.Text = string.Format("{0:0.000}", myValue);
```

I tried this before:

```
lblTotal.Text = string.Format("{0:#.###}", myValue);
```

Nothing works!!! I want to show values from database that are in that format but when refresh the table with a postback for any operation, my values become just "0" but it must be "0.000". If it's "5.300" it changes to "5.3"

What am I doing wrong?

I don't what to include the format in the HTML. Just in the code behind at the moment of the repeater binding.

Comment: You're doing something else wrong. When I run `string.Format("{0:0.000}", myValue)` when `myValue = 1` I get: `1.000` Please post the repeater code.

Comment: Have you tried using the `f/F` format specifier when you declare `myValue`?  Like, `myValue = 5.300f/5.300F`?  See, [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#FFormatString) for more info.

Comment: You mean it works but resets to unformatted on postback?

Comment: Thanks to you all guys for your quick answer. @Brian, thanks for the article.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the .ToString() with a custom specifier. In the code below lblTotal.Text will be set to "5.300".

```
var myValue = 5.3;
lblTotal.Text = myValue.ToString("0.000");
```

Answer (score 4):

A format of "0.000" will show 5.3 as 5.300 and 0 will show 0.000

using "#" placeholders will only show the value if there is a value in that position.